# Cost Estimation of Satellite propulsion systems

Tags: artificial-satellite, propulsion, engines, cost, advanced-propulsion

As part of my research project, i am evaluating various satellite propulsion systems. Are there any databases or forums where the ROM cost of a Satellite propulsion system is listed.
A few new space companies have listed out the cost, however:

1. what would be the estimated non recurring cost of a Mono/Bi propellant system?
2. How is the cost scaling, as per increase in the thrust output?

Comment: What is ROM? Also do you mean launch systems or thrusters for station keeping

Comment: Definitely interested to see the answer to this question.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cost': Cost for building the satellite or do you want to take into account the weight of the propulsion system? (The higher the weight of the propulsion system, the more capable the lifter has to be. Therefore, the lifter might become more expensive as well. This is a serious consideration for satellite manufacterors, since launch vehicles aren't cheap)

Comment: By ROM, i meant the rough order of magnitude Cost. As per my understanding, the cost of a satellite propulsion system isn't something which can be quantified easily. There are certain ball park references however the definitive cost isn't listed.

Comment: And by Cost, i don't mean the Mass or the power budget, but the financial estimate towards implementing a propulsion system in a given satellite bus.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how long this project is going to last, but if you're a grad student or something, using the Aerospace Corp's Small Satellite Cost Model has a good bit of cost estimating relationships (CERs) for multiple satellite subsystems.

http://www.aerospace.org/research/space-systems-infrastructure/small-satellite-cost-model/

If that's not feasible, there are a couple different CERs that you may be able to pull from some references here:

http://www.dtic.mil/get-tr-doc/pdf?AD=ADA308665

http://www.iceaaonline.com/ready/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/EST01-Broder.pdf

I looked through a PDF of an old edition of the SMAD, and didn't see much that I think would be of use to you.  A newer edition may however.